# handover a javascript variable to html

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

I have 2 files, `filter.html` and `filter.js`.
In `filter.html` I have a div with the id "test" and in `filter.js` I have a variable with the name "finishedHTML".

Now I want to write the content of "finishedHTML" into the test div as html code, but the html things "finishedHTML" is empty.
How can I solve this problem?

**Source:**

```js
var finishedHTML = "<h2>Yes it works</h2>"
```

```css
header {
  display: block;
  background: #A2AFBC;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;  
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #A2AFBC;
  position: fixed;
}
.headerTitle {
  font-size: 2.0em;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #506B84;
  margin: 0em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3.0 em;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>    
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" >
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" >
    <!--Filter.js-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="filter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <span class="headerTitle">Header Text</span>
    </header>

    <div id="test" style="margin-left: 300px; padding-top: 300px;">
        <h1>This is a test text</h1>
    </div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = finishedHTML;
    </script>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks four your help!

Comment: Where are you declaring `finishedHTML`?

Comment: Yes, where the hell is finishedHTML?

Comment: your code works. i've created these 2 files and get the correct result.

Comment: now it works. i simply write the "document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = finishedHTML;" into filter.js. how i can mark this answer as solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable `finishedHTML` only after it has been declared. So declare it at any point before setting the `innerHTML` and it will work.

```js
var finishedHTML = "<h2>Yes it works</h2>";
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = finishedHTML;
```

```css
header {
        display: block;
        background: #A2AFBC;
        top: 0;
        height: 50px;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;  
        text-align: center;
    }
    
footer {
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        background: #A2AFBC;
        position: fixed;
    }
.headerTitle {
    font-size: 2.0em;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #506B84;
    margin: 0em;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3.0 em;
  color: red;
  
}
```

```html
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" >
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" >
        <!--Filter.js-->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="filter.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <span class="headerTitle">Header Text</span>
        </header>
        <!-- style="margin-left: 300px; padding-top: 300px;"-->
        <div id="test" style="margin-top: 100px;">
            <h1>This is a test text</h1>
        </div>
        
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am an idiot.. thank you for your help, i will vote it up if i have enough Rep. have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Move `document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = finishedHTML;` into filter.js.

Comment: @letsTry420 please consider upvoting/accepting this answer for future users

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" >
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <span class="headerTitle">Header Text</span>
        </header>

        <div id="test" style="margin-left: 300px; padding-top: 300px;">
            <h1>This is a test text</h1>
        </div>
        <!--Filter.js-->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="filter.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = finishedHTML;
        </script>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

put `<script>` inside body can solve your asysnc loading script issue

Answer (score 0):

Hey just check this its working fine for me.
Thanks

```html
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" >
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" >
        <!--Filter.js-->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="filter.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <span class="headerTitle">Header Text</span>
        </header>
        
        <div id="test" style="margin-left: 300px; padding-top: 30px;">
            <h1>This is a test text</h1>
        </div>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            var finishedHTML = "<h2>Yes it works</h2>";
            console.log(finishedHTML);
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = finishedHTML;
        </script>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```